# Laravel AUTH() - Adding additional users (without registration)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've tried to find information on this and can't find any.  I have a Laravel 7 application and have used the Laravel AUTH scaffolding for login/registration/authentication.

I would like to allow a logged in user to add other users, I've done the simply but pushing the data in to the database (obviously no password is set) but now I would like to send an email to these users asking them to set a password and am unsure how to do this.  I see Laravel has some events related to auth built in such as this called in the **register** function of **RegistersUsers.php**:

```
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
```

Can anyone confirm where I would need to create such an event and how I call it from the store function that adds the user to the database?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you would call it like that, but passing the user you created to the constructor of the event

Comment: I create users with a random password, and use the pass reset functionality (with some other texts in the mail and the view)

Comment: Thanks chaps, I've done as @lagbox suggested and passed the user object to the event constructor.  For the password reset, that's my fall back but I'd hoped for something more controller so I'll look if I can duplicate the password reset functionality with a customer welcome message instead (e.g. Click here to set the password for your new account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @lagbox I simply did the following:

```
$user = \App\User::create([
            'firstname' => $validatedData['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $validatedData['lastname'],
            'email' => $validatedData['email'],
            'company_id' => $company_id,
            'phone_number' => $validatedData['phone_number'],
            'password' => Str::random(16),
        ]);

    event(new Registered($user));
```